# Testing web page speed

Tags: internet, webpage

How can I test the speed of a web page?

How can I further diagnose a page so that I can see which elements in the page take longer to load?

Comment: This would be better asked on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) and [Page Speed](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/)

It is an open-source Firefox/Firebug Add-on. Webmasters and web developers can use Page Speed to evaluate the performance of their web pages and to get suggestions on how to improve them.

Answer (score 1):

**How can I test the speed of a web page?**

> This site http://www.webpagetest.org/
> offers a online tool to find your web-page loading speed
>
> Other online tools include:
>
> http://www.linkvendor.com/seo-tools/speedtester.html
>
> http://www.iwebtool.com/speed_test
>
> http://www.vertain.com/?sst
>
> http://tools.pingdom.com/
>
> Also Page Speed is an excellent
> Firefox/Firebug Add-on
> http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/

**Some tips in reducing loading speed could be :**

- Remove unwanted Things like background sound, big animation files, unwanted java-script codes
- Try to use more CSS
- Avoid use of Nested Tables
- Use GIF instead of JPEG . Try to use image files that take low disk space.

Answer (score 1):

Google Chrome has some very detailed metrics for the request/response, downloading of the content, parsing, presentation, etc.

Right Click on a page and "Inspect Element".  They also have [a huge number of development tools](http://www.chromium.org/devtools/google-chrome-developer-tools-tutorial) tucked away behind that menu item.

Answer (score 0):

If by "which elements" you mean which HTTP requested objects, then client-side tools like Firebug's "net" tab ([see here](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel)) will help for simple cases and many less than simple ones.

If you are needing to diagnose elements within a scripted page then that will depend greatly on what language/framework/servers you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I use this tool 24x7:

http://pingdom.com/

And the free tests at:

http://www.gomez.com/

Here's examples of the response time test and multibrowser tests:

http://tovare.com/gfx/performance/Gome_210710.pdf

http://tovare.com/gfx/performance/Gome_multibrowser_210710.pdf

I also use the built in features in chrome, but since I'm on a netbook in a country far far away from my server, there's too much going on to do reliable tests.

Answer (score 0):

AlertFox has a very easy to use test for global page load times:

http://www.alertfox.com/Tools/LoadTime/